# SQL - Display value in column when left join fails

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Let's say I want to join on 2 tables, one is filled like this.

```
| Category  |
|-----------|
| id | name |
|----|------|
|  1 | Foo  |
|  2 | Bar  |
|  3 | Baz  |
```

The other like this:

```
|   Page    |
|-----------|
| id | cat  |
|----|------|
|  1 | 0    |
|  2 | 1    |
|  3 | 3    |
```

As you can see cat 0 in the `Page` table is not present in the `Category` table. Our system is unfortunately like this and I can't add the category with id `0` to the `Category` table, due to other code.

Now comes the one million dollar question: Is it possible to join `category.id` on `page.cat` and set an if statement when `page.cat` equals `0` to show the category name as `Default`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: What result you expect after the JOIN ?

Comment: I expect that I can show a category name on the page with id 1 which equals `Default`. For example I show category `Foo` on page with id 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If only 0 is the one missing do a left join and use `COALESCE` to decode the nulls.

```
SELECT Page.*, COALESCE(name , 'Default')
FROM Page
LEFT JOIN Category
  ON Page.cat = Category.id;
```

or

```
SELECT P.*, IFNULL(C.name , 'Default') as Name   
FROM Page P   
LEFT JOIN Category C ON P.cat= C.id
```

Comment: This will work no matter how many missing values there are. It'll just return the same thing for all of them. Which may or may not be what the OP wants, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yes, I just realize that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.cat,
    case when p.cat = 0 then "DEFAULT" ELSE c.name END AS cat_name
FROM 
    cat c RIGHT JOIN page p
ON c.id = p.cat
ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: This doesnt work. the `p.cat = 0` doesnt have anyone to join to